# How to determine return code of MSI when it's called from Setup.exe bootstrapper

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, batch-file, windows-installer, setup-project

We have a Win Forms application that is built from VS 2010, and has a VS Setup project which creates an MSI and a Setup.exe as the bootstrapper.

The MSI is included in a self-extracting 7zip file that calls a batch file when it extracts, and that batch file in the past would execute the MSI directly with the `/passive` switch, and it would give different messages depending on the return code, like shown below...

```
IF %ErrorLevel% EQU 1602 GOTO :INSTALL_CANCELLED
IF %ErrorLevel% NEQ 0 GOTO :INSTALL_FAILED
```

Executing the MSI directly means that the bootstrap process is skipped and prerequisites don't get installed if they are needed.  So I want to change this so that we include the Setup.exe bootstrapper in the package, and execute `Setup.exe /passive` instead of calling the MSI directly.

This works fine, unless something goes wrong, in which case the `%ErrorLevel%` is still returned as 0.  I'm assuming this is because Setup.exe calls the MSI, and regardless of whether the MSI hit an error or not, the Setup.exe exits with return code of 0.

Is there any way to detect whether the MSI returns a non-zero code if I'm calling Setup.exe instead of calling the MSI directly?

*EDIT

I found this MSDN article, which says the following...

> Note that the Setup.exe Bootstrapper sample does not need to check for
>   error codes generated by the host application, myapp, because this is
>   not a silent install and all errors are displayed to the user through
>   the Windows Installer user interface.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1cfs8(v=vs.90).aspx#cpconsetupexebootstrappersampleoperationsanchor4

WTF do they mean "Because this is not a silent install"?  The hell it isn't.  They support passing the /passive switch to make it a silent install, but then they give you no way to get a return code from the MSI, in their words "because this is not a silent install".

Well now I'm just ranting about a deprecated Visual Studio feature, so I guess it is what it is.

Comment: If the source code to the bootstrapper sample is available, it should be easy enough to modify it.  Alternatively, if the VS Setup project is used only for this purpose (or can be split into two variants) you could presumably build an .msi that is naturally passive unless an error occurs - or does the bootstrapper itself require interaction even if the .msi doesn't?

Comment: I would love to have and modify the source code, but I can't find it. If anyone does, please let me know.

To the OP, it's possible that dotNetInstaller (http://dblock.github.io/dotnetinstaller/) would work for your needs. I just discovered this, so can't really be sure, but thought I'd mention in case it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The setup.exe would have to surface the exit code.

FWIW, Windows Installer XML (WiX) has a bootstrapper (Burn) that you can customize (implementing a bootstrapper application layer)  and do anything you want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to not have to write my own custom bootstrapper, and don't want to replace the entire VS Setup project with a WIX setup project.  Was hoping there would be some way for the basic Setup.exe bootstrapper you get with a VS Setup project to surface the exit code of the MSI, but I guess it doesn't.  I found this documentation from MSDN that says it doesn't do it because the MSI wouldn't be running as a silent install.  The hell is isn't!  ...  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1cfs8(v=vs.90).aspx#cpconsetupexebootstrappersampleoperationsanchor4

Comment: By creating a self extracting zip that calls a batch script file... aren't you basically writing a custom bootstrapper?

Comment: I didn't write the original code, and it's kind of a long story, but I can't change the bit about the self extracting zip file.  It was in the past used as sort of a poor man's bootstrapper, but it was flawed and I'd rather use the Setup.exe bootstrapper that is generated from the VS Setup project.  The self extracting zip file is actually returned by a remote service call when clients find that they're out of date and need to upgrade, so I really can't remove that part.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: I misread the question; I thought you were running someone else's setup project.  However, since this answer might still be useful to someone, and I've already written it, I'm posting it anyway.*

Not easily, and not from batch.

If you launch the setup process [within a job object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can assign it to a completion port and listen for the `JOB_OBJECT_MSG_NEW_PROCESS` message.  You would then have to open the new process, check whether it is `msiexec.exe` and keep the process handle if so.

When the setup process is finished, use the stored process handle for `msiexec.exe` to retrieve the exit code via [GetExitCodeProcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).